# ERROR: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-bo@script/Jenkinsfile not found

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean, maven-module

I have a maven multi modules project.
I create a pipeline to clean and deploy my project.
When I run the pipeline I got the following output :

```
``Started by user XXXXX
Checking out git http://XXXX:9080/gara/gara-back-end.git into /var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-bo@script to read Jenkinsfile
using credential XXXXXXXXXXX
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://XXXXXXX:9080/gara/gara-back-end.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://XXXXX:9080/gara/gara-back-end.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress http://XXXXXX:9080/gara/gara-back-end.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c717022003b698421698238b13e1909f555172a0 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Commit message: "Update  Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX # timeout=10
ERROR: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/gara-bo@script/Jenkinsfile not found
Finished: FAILURE``
```

Why the project is checked out under gara-bo@script instead of gara-bo ?
On the server, I have two folders : gara-bo  and gara-bo@script

```
``gara-bo contains : Jenkinsfile  pom.xml  src  target  WEB-INF
gara-bo@script : gara-common  gara-dao  gara-model  gara-service  gara-web   JenkinsFile  pom.xml``
```

but file in the gara-bo@script are just symbolic link because when I try to read the content of JenkinsFile  under gara-bo@script it is impossible.

Do you know, how could I correct it please ?

Comment: Please could you help me ?

Comment: I am stuck with a similar issue. Is this resolved ?

Comment: yes. When I create the Jenkinsfile, i Add a space in the name. So please check that the name doesn't contain a space. You have to have "Jenkinsfile", not " Jenkinsfile" or "Jenkinsfile ", etc...

Comment: Facing the same issue.. did anyone find solution?

Comment: @Ramkrushna26 please read the validated answer.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko faced different issue ... it was minor wrt project config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create the Jenkinsfile, i Add a space in the name. So please check that the name doesn't contain a space. You have to have "Jenkinsfile", not " Jenkinsfile" or "Jenkinsfile ", etc...

Answer (score 2):

That is because there are many other branches which didn’t contain a Jenkins file yet.

Probably it it the first time you are using Jenkins. So the Jenkins file in only in your current developing branch (E.g: `YOUR_BRANCH-79`).

Here don't use `:origin/YOUR_BRANCH-.*`, you can use `:origin/YOUR_BRANCH-79`.

[image]